# Why I get differences of length between 2 ways: dict and array

Tags: python, python-2.7

*hashes* is a generator.

```
  mapper = {}
  for hash, offset in hashes:
      mapper[hash.upper()] = offset
  len(mapper)
```

Length of mapper: 1444

```
hashlist = []
for hash in hashes:
    hashlist.append(hash)
len(hashlist)
```

Length of hashlist: 1477

---

That's what I don't understand!

Comment: Clearly you have duplicate hashes when uppercased.

Comment: There could be possibility that there could be duplicate values in the list, where as dictionary does not hold duplicate keys. One way you to be sure, you could convert your list to set and then check its length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly you have duplicate hashes when uppercased. Keys in a dictionary are unique, and using the same (uppercased) hash as a key in a dictionary will replace the previous value for that key.

In your case, you have 33 hashes that, when uppercased, already appeared before.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a possibility that there is duplicate elements in the list, as dictionary does not hold duplicate keys. One way you to be sure, you could convert your list to a set and then check its length.

```
hashlist = []
for hash in hashes:
    hashlist.append(hash)
len(hashlist) # This gives the length of list which can contain duplicate values.

len(set(hashlist)) # This gives the length of list with unique values in it.
```

In case you need to find duplicates elements from your list

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]

import collections
print [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1]

## [1, 2, 5]
```